# Interface overriding giving error. Overriding public state variable return types differ

Tags: interfaces, inheritance, override

I am trying to import interface in it's contract and overriding function. But 1 mapping is giving error.

Error:

```
Overriding public state variable return types differ.
```

Interface:

```
interface IPassCurrencies {
    function currencyMapping(uint128 currencyIndex)
        external
        view
        returns (PLibrary.CurrencyInfo memory);

}
```

Contract:

```
contract Currencies is Ownable, ReentrancyGuard, IPassCurrencies {
    mapping(uint128 => PLibrary.CurrencyInfo)
        public
        override currencyMapping; // Error Here
        ....
}
```

Any idea where I am wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to decouple your struct, try something like this:

```
function currencyMapping(uint128 currencyIndex)
        external
        view
        returns (address addr, uint8 decimals);
```

Assuming you struct is as follow:

```
struct CurrencyInfo {
  address addr,
  uint8 decimals
}
```

Comment: But won't that affect the point of returning a struct, because now I will be getting multiple values in return rather than the struct object I am expecting?

Comment: I agree, i've no idea why solidity currently throw on the syntax you provided :目
It seems more like a bug. But at least for now that is what you need to make the compiler silent.